# How can I return a list of specific words found in a cell's contents?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, conditional-statements

I have two columns, one with a string of text (`A1`), the other blank (`A2`).

`A1` looks something like this:

> "Briefs on Southern Africa, Rhodesia, East of Suez (Including Soviet
>   Naval Expansion), Arab-Israel dispute, hijacking, East-West Relations,
>   NATO, Britain and the European Communities"

I need to enter the names of countries featured in `A1` into `A2`. For example, above I would enter `Rhodesia, Soviet Union, Israel, United Kingdom`.

Is there a formula I can use to find specific words and then drop them into `A2`?

Comment: By the way, I know Rhodesia isn't a country anymore, but for the sake of my work let's go with it.

Comment: Do you have a list of words/countries you are looking for? And how do you want the output formatted? A comma-separated list in A2?

Comment: How do you get "Soviet Union" and "UK", but not "Britain"?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make a chain of functions. The following steps worked in Excel 2010 and presume you only have the aforementioned text in `A1`:

1. Copy the following formula into cell `B1`:

   - `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,","," "),"-"," "),"(",""),")","")`
   - This formula only accounts for the punctuation included in your original text. In order to catch more punctuation, you'll have to wrap this formula with another SUBSTITUTE(*<<current formula>>*, *<<punctuation in quotes>>*, *<<either "" or " " depending on the desired result>>*).
2. Name cell `B1` "SearchText" (without the quotes). You can do this as follows:

   - Press `Alt,M,M,D` to open the `New Name` dialog. Overwrite the suggested name and press `Enter`.
   - Click on the `Name Box` just to the left of the formula edit bar, then type the name, and press `Enter`.
3. Enter your list of countries into column `D`, starting with cell `D1`.
4. Select column `D` and name it "Countries" as indicated previously.
5. In cell `C1`, enter the following formula:

   - `=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(CONCATENATE(Countries," "),SearchText),FALSE),Countries,"")`
6. In cell `C2`, enter the following formula:

   - `=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(CONCATENATE(Countries," "),SearchText),FALSE),IF(C1="",Countries,CONCATENATE(C1,", ",Countries)), C1)`
7. Copy `C2` and paste it the whole way down the column, ending at (presuming 196 countries) cell `C196`.
8. In cell `A2`, enter the following formula: `=C196`

   - You can hide or group columns `B` through `D` to tidy things up.

Every time you enter a new bit of text into `A1`, the formulas will recalculate and your results will appear in `A2`. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks Skia.Heliou for your response! I tried this out last week and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much again, and sorry for not getting back to you sooner.

Comment: @Tom M: You're welcome! I'm glad it worked for you. Would you vote up my response and select it as the answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this small User Defined Function:

```
Public Function XtractNations(t As String) As String
    Dim Nations(1 To 48) As String
    Dim s As String
    Nations(1) = "China"
    Nations(2) = "Japan"
    Nations(3) = "Germany"
    Nations(4) = "France"
    Nations(5) = "United Kingdom"
    Nations(6) = "Brazil"
    Nations(7) = "Russia"
    Nations(8) = "Italy"
    Nations(9) = "India"
    Nations(10) = "Canada"
    Nations(11) = "Australia"
    Nations(12) = "Spain"
    Nations(13) = "Mexico"
    Nations(14) = "South Korea"
    Nations(15) = "Indonesia"
    Nations(16) = "Turkey"
    Nations(17) = "Netherlands"
    Nations(18) = "Saudi Arabia"
    Nations(19) = "Switzerland"
    Nations(20) = "Iran"
    Nations(21) = "Sweden"
    Nations(22) = "Norway"
    Nations(23) = "Poland"
    Nations(24) = "Belgium"
    Nations(25) = "Argentina"
    Nations(26) = "Austria"
    Nations(27) = "Thailand"
    Nations(28) = "South Africa"
    Nations(29) = "United Arab Emirates"
    Nations(30) = "Venezuela"
    Nations(31) = "Colombia"
    Nations(32) = "Denmark"
    Nations(33) = "Malaysia"
    Nations(34) = "Singapore"
    Nations(35) = "Chile"
    Nations(36) = "Hong Kong"
    Nations(37) = "Nigeria"
    Nations(38) = "Egypt"
    Nations(39) = "Philippines"
    Nations(40) = "Greece"
    Nations(41) = "Finland"
    Nations(42) = "Israel"
    Nations(43) = "Pakistan"
    Nations(44) = "Portugal"
    Nations(45) = "Ireland"
    Nations(46) = "Algeria"
    Nations(47) = "Peru"
    Nations(48) = "Kazakhstan"
    s = ""
    For i = 1 To 48
        If InStr(1, t, Nations(i)) > 0 Then
            s = s & ", " & Nations(i)
        End If
    Next i
    XtractNations = Right(s, Len(s) - 1)
End Function
```

You can add as many countries to the list as you like.